# file_get_contents - authorisation and sending data

Tags: post, get, authorization, file-get-contents

How can I send GET / POST data to server which require authorisation using file_get_contents?

I know how to send GET/POST data and authorise in file_get_contents but don't know who to combine these in one.
Can someone help?

Comment: Test by putting the login-info like this http://username:password@filelocation.com/file.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, something like that with a context for (re)set options from the protocol used :

```
function http_post($url, $data) {
$serialized_data = http_build_query($data);
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" . 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($serialized_data) . "\r\n",
        'content' => $serialized_data
    )
);
$contexte = stream_context_create($options);
return file_get_contents($url, 0, $contexte);
```

}

$content = http_post('http://domain/mypage', array('var1' => 'val1', /* ... */, 'varN' => 'valN'));

Do you want more explication ?